# What's the method to control volume in an MIDI sequencer?

Tags: java, audio, sequence, volume, midi

Can someone show me how to control the volume of an MIDI sequencer **without** using a sound bank or synthesizer?

I want to make the MIDI fade out before continuing to the next MIDI in sequence

```
            if(midiplay)
            {

                midi = s + savereq;
                try {
                    //System.out.println("Play MIDI " + midi);
                    if (musicSr != null)
                    {
                                               /* This is where I want it to fade out*/
                        musicSr.stop(); //stop sequencer
                        musicSr.close(); //close sequencer
                    }
                    musicSr = null; 
                    musicS = null;

                    File music = new File(midi);
                    if(music.exists())
                    {
                        musicS = MidiSystem.getSequence(music);
                    }

                    // Create a sequencer for the sequence
                    musicSr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
                            musicSr.open();
                            musicSr.setSequence(musicS);
                            musicSr.setLoopCount(musicSr.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
                            musicSr.start();

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


                midiplay = false;

            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to controll the MIDI channel's volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008286/how-to-controll-the-midi-channels-volume)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth that question has synthesizer and sound banks, which I am not using.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento How would I do that? Can I have a snippet/example of use

Comment: To face out, you use the volume controller as explained in the "How to controll the MIDI channel's volume" question linked by Oli.

Comment: @BjornRoche That answer works only with a `Synthesizer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Call [getSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequencer.html#getSequence%28%29) to get the [Sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequence.html);
2. call [getTracks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequence.html#getTracks%28%29) to get the list of tracks;
3. in each track, for each channel used in the track, call [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Track.html#add%28javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent%29) to add multiple events at the appropriate time positions:

   ```
   track.add(new MidiEvent(
       new ShortMessage(ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, channel, 7, volume),
       tick));
   ```
4. maybe remove other volume change events (that would interfere with your fadeout) from the track;
5. wait a little time for the fadeout to happen.